# Extract parameters from JSON response with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need select parameters in JSON response with DAX. For example.
[{ "firstName":"fname", "lastName":"lname", "department": { "department":"d1", "location":"l1"} }, { "firstName":"fname2", "lastName":"lname2", "department": { "department":"d2", "location":"l2"} }]. I need select only department properties. Is this posible?

Comment: Me respondo a mi mismo. En la respuesta de la petición no me lo muestra, sin embargo, al acceder a la DATA y pedir la columna correspondiente a los objetos, en la cabecera se muestra un icono, para expandir las propiedades del objeto que buscaba